# Change Wifi conncetion on a Mobile App using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I m using **Flutter 1.26.0**. I have tried out WIFI connecting part using Flutter **wifi: ^0.1.5** dependencies. I have tried out to change wifi to another router using **Flutter_wifi_connect, wifi_connect, wifi_iot**. But all of them ended up with a error. I m using an android phone to debug. I think there is a problem with wifi permission inside the android files.

Comment: Did all of them have the same error?

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Yes It seems like same I have now using manual wifi connecting to my task in the mobile application